# BizTalk 2013 CU2 + ESB : Failed to update resources in the application

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment, biztalk-2013

Recently upgraded to `BizTalk 2013 CU2` and installed ESB.

This has had some side effects as we can no longer deploy without getting a `database FK reference error`.

Any one seen this before?

Here is the error when we try to deploy a new assembly to the DEV environment.

---

### TITLE: BizTalk Server Administration

Failed to update resources in the application.

---

### ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Failed to add resource(s). (`mscorlib`)

---

Change requests failed for some resources. (`Microsoft.BizTalk.ApplicationDeployment.Engine`)

---

BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed to complete end type change request. (`Microsoft.BizTalk.ResourceManagers`)

---

Removal of the assembly failed. Make sure that all items in the assembly you are trying to remove fulfill the following conditions:

1. Pipelines, maps, and schemas are not being used by Send Ports or Receive Locations in the same or referenced application(s).
2. Roles have no enlisted parties.

Database Error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   `bts_receiveport_transform_foreign_transformid`. The conflict occurred
>   in database "BizTalkMgmtDb", table "dbo.bts_receiveport_transform",
>   column 'uidTransformGUID'. The DELETE statement conflicted with the
>   REFERENCE constraint "fk_bt_mapspec_bts_item". The conflict occurred
>   in database "BizTalkMgmtDb", table "dbo.bt_MapSpec", column 'itemid'.
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "bts_receiveport_transform_foreign_transformid". The conflict occurred
>   in database "BizTalkMgmtDb", table "dbo.bts_receiveport_transform",
>   column 'uidTransformGUID'. The statement has been terminated. The
>   statement has been terminated. The statement has been terminated.
>   (mscorlib)

---

I ran a SQL trace and found that this is the SP that breaks when it tries to delete from table `dbo.bt_MapSpec`.

> exec dpl_DeleteAssembly
>   @Guid=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',@Name=N'theassemblynamegoeshere',@VersionMajor=1,@VersionMinor=0,@VersionBuild=0,@VersionRevision=0,@PublicKeyToken=N'89e32fae0caf808e',@Culture=N'neutral',@Type=N'2',@NoSchemasVerify=0

Comment: Found the issue - This is caused when you install the CU2 pack for MS BizTalk 2013. Once I un-istalled the CU2 then issue went away.

Comment: Try removing the maps from the receive ports.

Comment: I opted for uninstalling the CU2 pack as we found other issues with this pack - Some legacy code would not compile successfully. CU3 is also just around the corner, so will wait for this one.